# C++ Concatenate two char * to LPTSTR for command line arguments

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm new to C++, but I'm trying to build a program in Windows to play around with concurrency in which a parent process will start a child process. Is there a Windows function that will take arg1 and arg2 from my method, `BuildChildProcess(char * arg1, char * arg2)`, and concatenate those two parameters to a `LPTSTR` command line string to be used in the CreateProcess function?

I orginally tried `strcat` with just one of the parameters before I learned that it's unsafe, so I then tried `strcat_s` but either it doesn't work for what I'm trying to do or I just did it wrong. If I should use it, then a working example of it's use would help.

Thanks

Edit:
Basically, how can I concatenate two `char *` C style strings (arg1 and arg2) to the end of the *lpCommandLine* parameter of the `CreateProcess` function, which is type `LPTSTR`?

Comment: Seriously, string handling in C++ is covered in any good C++ book or tutorial.   Also, use `std::string` instead of raw char pointers.  As to your question, you could be doing so much wrong, not just with using pointers, but the possible type mismatches with `LPTSTR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use C++ you can use the standard library strings. Your use of `TCHAR` is confusing. Is it `char` or `wchar_t`? If the former, why not support Unicode? You should not need to use `TCHAR` which only exists to help with code that needs to run on Windows 9x which had no Unicode support.

From other parts of your question you wish to concatenate two `char*` C strings named `arg1` and `arg2`. Do that like this:

```
#include <string>
....
std::string str1 = arg1;
std::string str2 = arg2;
std::string combined = str1 + str2;
```

It could be written more concisely but I want to make it explicit for you.

Then pass `combined.c_str()` if you need a `const char*` or `&combined[0]` if you need a `char*`. The latter option for a `char*` requires that you are using C++-11 or later.

Personally I'd be using the native wide Unicode API here. That means `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`.

Comment: I'm using the multi-byte character set, so `TCHAR` becomes `char` right? Also, I'm not necessarily trying to concat the two args together by themselves. I'm looking for a way to concat both of them to the end of the _lpCommandLine_ parameter of the `CreateProcess` function, which is of type `LPTSTR`.

Comment: Well, my answer shows how to do that. Still, why are you using TCHAR? You are not meant to do that any more. Or do you want to support Win98?

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to C++ so I don't fully understand the difference between all of the types just yet (yeah, yeah, I know...read the MSDN documentation and google things I don't know), but I'm just trying to get experience with using them in various ways.

Comment: Well, stop using TCHAR. To be fair, there are lots of ancient MSDN examples that lead you that way. Anyway, don't be misled. I've shown you how to concatenate strings, and then interop with win32. Isn't that what you asked?

Comment: Sort of. I know I'm starting to sound like a broken record here, but suppose I have `LPTSTR commandLineToExec = "C:\\Solution\\Child.exe";` inside my  `BuildChildProcess(char* arg1, char* arg2)` function and I want to end up with `LPTSTR commandLineToExec = "C:\\Solution\\Child.exe arg1 arg2";` before sending it to Windows' `CreateProcess` function. `CreateProcess` requires `LPTSTR` for its second parameter, but I'm not understanding how to add C style strings to a `LPTSTR`.

Comment: It's explained in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
BuildChildProcess(char * arg1, char * arg2){
     char buff[256];
     sprintf_s(buff, 256, TEXT("%s%s"), arg1, arg2);
     .........
}
```

Then **buff** will contain two of your char*'s. If you need to work with unicode strings then unicode version of sprintf_s is needed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx

If you need to convert from char to UNICODE then there is API function **[MultiByteToWideChar()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx)**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear with my question. I have a `LPTSTR` for the "command line to execute" (i.e. _lpCommandLine_) parameter in `CreateProcess`, and I want to concatenate arg1 and arg2 to it. Would your example work for that?

Comment: LPTSTR is a pointer to char in multibyte project. So is **buff**. The best way to find out will it work or not is to try.

Comment: @Johnny No. The best way is to understand and not use trial and error.

Comment: @ David Heffernan Definitely. But still there is always room for trying. That's how progress goes.